# How to list model based off ID?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I can't get my controller to list the contractor model based off User Id. I need it display the contractors that a user made.

Could someone tell what I'm missing to list it correctly?

I'm getting an error in the line

```
  Return View(Contractors)
```

Saying it doesn't exist in the current context so I have no idea how to pass the model into the view.

What I have so far is:

```
// GET: Admin/Shop/Products
public ActionResult MyContractors(int? catId)
{
        using (Db db = new Db())
        {
            UserDTO user = db.Users.Where(x => x.Username == User.Identity.Name).FirstOrDefault();
            int userId = user.UserId;

            // Declare a list of ProductVM
            List<ContractorVM> Contractors = db.Contractors.Where(x => x.UserId == userId).ToArray().Select(x => new ContractorVM(x)).ToList();

            // Populate categories select list
            ViewBag.ContractorCategories = new SelectList(db.ContractorCategories.ToList(), "ContractorCategoryId", "ContractorCategoryName");

            // Set selected category
            ViewBag.SelectedCat = catId.ToString();
        }

        // Return view with list
        return View(Contractors);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've created `Contractors` inside `using (Db db = new Db())`. Nothing outside of this knows it exists, that's why it's saying it's not in the current context.

Declare outside that such as this:

```
List<ContractorVM> Contractors = new List<ContractorVM>()
```

and then inside assign it a vale such as:

```
Contractors = db.Contractors.Where(x => x.UserId == userId).ToArray().Select(x => new ContractorVM(x)).ToList();
```

and it should work